# Understanding eye.getEyeView() and eye.getPerspective matrices

Tags: matrix, google-cardboard, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

I understand the roles of Eye.getEyeView and Eye.getPerspective matrices, at least according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/base/Eye.html).  The first takes the position of the camera and transforms it to the position of the current eye.  This takes into account head tracking and the offset of each pupil.  The second just gives a perspective projection matrix, this doesn't depend on the headtracking, only on the field of view for each eye.

What I don't understand is the difference between the field of view for each eye.  Our eyes are approximately forward facing, so should they be the same?  Well the matrices are actually rather different.  Let's take a look, these were logged in the onDrawEye method using a variant of the TreasureHunt example in the SDK:

Left EyeView matrix:

```
 0.99938333   &  0.013064715  & 0.03259317   & 0.0 \\
-0.022139862  &  0.95490175   & 0.2960955    & 0.0 \\
-0.02725487   & -0.2966345    & 0.9546021    & 0.0 \\ 
 0.03028951   & -0.0033823675 & 0.10220718   & 1.0
```

Right EyeView matrix:

```
  0.99938333  &  0.013064715   & 0.03259317 & 0.0 \\
 -0.022139862 &  0.95490175    & 0.2960955  & 0.0 \\
 -0.02725487  & -0.2966345     & 0.9546021  & 0.0 \\
 -0.03361049  & -0.0033823675  & 0.10220718 & 1.0
```

These are identical except for a_{41} which differs by about 0.064.  With units being metres I guess this is the distance between pupils?  I can see why the 3x3 orientation matrix would be identical.  But I can't make sense of why the other two varying values, a_{42} and a_{43} on the fourth row aren't different.  The eye position isn't different in only one axis! This isn't by chance it's common to every frame.

Now let's examine the perspective matrices:

Left Perspective matrix:

```
 0.8990804   &  0.0        &  0.0       &  0.0 \\ 
 0.0         &  0.762166   &  0.0       &  0.0 \\
 0.106264874 &  0.08848558 & -1.00002   & -1.0 \\
 0.0         &  0.0        & -0.0200002 &  0.0
```

Right Perspective matrix:

```
  0.89908034 & 0.0        &  0.0       &  0.0 \\ 
  0.0        & 0.762166   &  0.0       &  0.0 \\
 -0.10626444 & 0.08848558 & -1.00002   & -1.0 \\ 
  0.0        & 0.0        & -0.0200002 &  0.0
```

These only differ in a_{31}.  I don't think it makes sense to apply units to that value, (but correct me if I'm wrong).  This would seem to shift the output image by about by 0.1 either left or right.  I would expect these two matrices to be equal and the difference to be taken into account in the eyeView matrix.  Changing both to equal 0 ruins the 3D effect.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that the view matrix is off in the x-axis by that amount - that's a standard inter pupillary distance that is supported in Daydream. Remember, your view matrices transform the world around the viewpoint so the center of view is at the original and pointed up/down (depending on API) the Z axis with Y going up, so motion in the x-axis makes sense.

If you look at the treasure hunt sample, they take into account the head position/rotation when multiplied by the head_view matrix.

As for the projection matrices, you generally want your eyes to toe correctly towards the focal point. This offset performs that operation - it's shifting the focal point, which slightly skews the projection. It's an off-center projection with ~45deg on the outer side of your eye and ~50deg on the inner side (device dependent).

-Tom